# Is there a such thing as "negated alternation", or "negated string classes", a la "negated character classes", in PCRE?

Tags: javascript, regex, pcre

Alright, so while the pattern `[abc]` matches a single character that is `a`, `b`, or `c`, the pattern `[^abc]` matches any given character that *isn't* `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Now if I substitue *string* for *character* in the above statement, it would still apply if I also changed the first pattern to an alternation construct like `(abc|def|ghi)`.   -- it would match a consecutive string of three characters equal to `abc`, `def`, or `ghi`.   What can I do to match any string of three characters that *isn't* equal to `abc`, `def`, or `ghi`?

Comment: You've tagged this both "javascript" and "pcre". Note that these do **not** have the same features in their regular expression implementations, although they are similar in many ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common question with regexes, and the short answer is "no", the way regular expressions operate doesn't provide a way of saying "any 3-letter string except ...".

*However*, some regular expression engines allow for what are called "negative look-ahead assertions". These are a little tricky to get your head around - [this explanation of lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) seems to cover it quite well, if a little technically.

The important thing about lookahead is that it is "zero-width" - it doesn't "use up" any of the string. So in Javascript you can match a string like this: `'abc123ghi'.match(/abc(?!def)...ghi/)` - the `(?!def)` says that there mustn't be the letters `'def'` after the `'abc'`, but the `...` needs to be there to say that there should be some other 3 characters there instead.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of negative lookaround, but wasn't clever enough to come up with that workaround.  Anyhow, cool -- thanks!

Comment: Or would that be for abc not followed by def but yes followed by three consecutive characters that are all the same as each other?

Comment: @adlwalrus Yes, that would work exactly the same - `.{3}` is exactly equivalent to `...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use negated lookahead to do some of what you're saying:

```
xyz(?!abc|def|ghi)
```

That means "xyz followed by anything except abc, def, or ghi".  It doesn't actually consume the source so after that you'd put stuff that should continue the match after "xyz". That is,

```
/xyz(?!abc|def|ghi)(\w*)/
```

matches "xyzhello", and the first capture group will contain "hello".