# Why is "negated alternation" or "negated string classes" not supported in JS Regexp, and perhaps others as well?

Tags: javascript, regex

I can have `/[abcd]/`, `/(ab|cd)/`, and `/[^wxyz]/`.  Why not `/(^wx|yz)/`

[Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437757/is-there-a-such-thing-as-negated-alternation-or-negated-string-classes-a-l/12437857#12437857) you can achieve an exactly identical effect by simply kludging the functionality together from other features, like so: `/(?!wx|yz)../`.

So why not just support the feature natively? Is there an underlying reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, imagine that `(^wx|yz)` means — as you apparently intend — "a two-character sequence that is neither `wx` nor `yz`". What would `(^vwx|yz)` mean? Would it mean "a two- or three-character sequence that is neither `vwx` nor `yz`"? Would it mean "*either* a three-character sequence that is not `vwx` and does not start with `yz`, *or* a two-character sequence that is `yz`"?

The power of the character-class notation `[...]` — what lets it support ranges `a-z`, what lets it support negation, etc. — is that it always matches a single character. As soon as you remove that restriction, it's no longer clear what these things would mean.

Comment: I suppose it could throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

What would you expect the behavior of `/(^wx|yz)/` to be?  To me it seems like an empty string would satisfy the "negated alternation" that you are proposing.  If you expect it to try to match the same number of characters, what about negated alternations that that uses variable length regular expressions?

What I'm trying to get at here is that a negated alternation is too ambiguous to implement, and the most obvious way to do it would be as a zero-width assertion anyway, so you can just use `(?!...)`.