# How can I match a greedily quantified string of non-'[' characters which doesn't contain the string '-&gt;' anywhere inside it?

Tags: javascript, regex, greedy, regex-lookarounds

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437757/is-there-a-such-thing-as-negated-alternation-or-negated-string-classes-a-l/12437857) is sort of a starting point, although I don't think it actually covers the scenario, or if it does, it's confusing me too much for me to wrap my head around how to apply it to what I need.  I wouldn't know whether to use `.` or `.....` and then I'm not sure how I would achieve the greedy, imprecise quantification.

Regexes make my head spin...

Comment: I feel like the way the two matching constructs would overlap in the pattern string is what's hanging me up: maybe something like `/(?!-&gt;)[^\]]+/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
((?!-&gt;)[^\]])+
```

The pattern first looks ahead to check that there's no `"-&gt;"` (the `(?!-&gt;)` part), and then matches any char other than a `"]"`. This is then repeated once or more.

You may want to "anchor" your pattern to validate the entire input string:

```
^((?!-&gt;)[^\]])+$
```

Comment: Ah, so what I [had](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550079/how-can-i-match-a-greedily-quantified-string-of-non-characters-which-doesnt/12550120#comment16901889_12550079) was right, and just missing parenthesized quantification, it seems?

Comment: `"-&gt;bb".match(/((?!-&gt;)[^\]])+/)` still `===` `&gt;bb`, though.  How can I only match the `'bb'`?

Comment: Ohhhh, is this one of those things that just isn't possible without negative lookbehind, and ergo, not possible in JS, period?

Comment: @adlwalrus, indeed, JS does not support negative look behind. However, even with negative look behind, you'd still have similar issues: the pattern `/(?<!-&gt;)[^\]]+/` would still match parts (or all) of `"-&gt;"`. See my **EDIT**.

Comment: I'm not sure if that would solve the problem, but I think it would serve an entirely different purpose, and not what I want to do.  I think the rest of my regex will deal with not catching parts of the -`"&gt;"`, so it's a moot issue.  Thanks for the tip, though.